# Is there a Python function or a library to get the structure of an heterogeneous json file?

Tags: python, json

I would like to know how can I get the structure of the general JSON object in a JSON file.

For exemple:

What I have:

```
{
  "firstname": "john11",
  "lastname": "doe11"
}
{
  "firstname": "john22",
  "lastname": "doe22",
  "age": "20"
}
{
  "firstname": "john33",
  "lastname": "doe33",
  "gender": "test"
}
```

The expected outpu of my lib/script/program:

```
{
  "firstname": "null",
  "lastname": "null",
  "age": "null",
  "gender": "null"
}
```

Another good output:

```
{
  "firstname": "john11",
  "lastname": "doe11",
  "age": "null",
  "gender": "null"
}
{
  "firstname": "john22",
  "lastname": "doe22",
  "age": "20",
  "gender": "null"
}
{
  "firstname": "john33",
  "lastname": "doe33",
  "age": "null",
  "gender": "test"
}
```

Comment: You have a list of dicts, you want to iterate through them all and make a set of the dict keys. Don't need a library for that. Please make an attempt and ask a specific question if you get stuck

Comment: The first "expected output" seems unrelated to the file's structure.  What are you looking for here?

Comment: I need a library for that because it is a 4 Gb file and the exemple is just an exemple, but the reality is that the structs are huge.

Answer (score 1):

Since `"}\n{"` is not legal json, and since that seems to be what's separating your dicts,

- Read in the file as a string
- Split on `"}\n{"` to get a list of strings, one per json object
- Reattach the trailing `"}"` and leading `"{"` for each string in the list
- Pass each string through `json.loads()` to get a list of dicts
- Collect the full set of keys by calling `d.keys()` for each dict `d` in the list.

Then merge those or use them to insert null values, or ...  ?